# Typescript compile check in build

Tags: typescript

I would like to check that typescript compiles successfully before merging to trunk.
For example, I sometimes get compile error

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Y'.
[client]   'Y' is a primitive, but 'X' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'Y' when possible.
```

or

```
error TS2322: Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Usually errors like this are caught when we run our application since our linting does not catch them but I would like these this to be caught on our build system. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "before merging", "on our build system" --- what performs a merge operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like these this to be caught on our build system

Yes. `tsc` will return error code `1` when there is a compile error that can be used by most build systems to fail a build.